# Export a Python List to Excel

Tags: python, excel, com

I am trying to export a list to excel via the Win32COM client whihc i have imported at the header.
The object i created is coded as below, but I cant seem to get it to export each value to its own row in the spreadsheet. If I can get a good pointer (other than give up python!! :D), I would appreciate it.

```
class XcelExport():
    def excel(self):
        app = 'Excel'
        xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('%s.Application' % app)
        ss = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\MyFile.xls')
        sh = ss.ActiveSheet
        xl.Visible = True
        sleep(.1)  
        sh.Cells(1,1).Value = 'Export-to-%s : Items' % app
        sleep(.1)
        for i in EventTableRFT:
            sh.Range("A").Value = i 
        sh.Cells(i+2,1).Value = "End of the List!"

xprt = XcelExport()
xprt.excel()
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use Win32COM rather than xlwt? `for i,e in enumerate(datalist): sheet.write(i,1,e)` would do what you want, after you open the book and sheet of course.

Comment: Why not just write it as a csv and use excel's own import facilities?

Comment: @Logan
Thanks mate. That worked perfect, I will look into xlwt/xlrd functionality as I need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you seemed to like my answer/comment, here's an answer proper:

[Python Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) has just about everything you'd ever need. If you want something more integrated but seems limited, there is [IronSpread](http://www.ironspread.com/index.html). XLRD and XLWT are great packages, but they don't support *.xlsx files. IronSpread is Windows only and only support '07 and '10 versions of Excel. Each has it's caveats. In the end, you can use both (edit as *.xlsx, then save as to *.xls (I had someone who had speed issues with large *.xls files, but my script wrote 200mb of text from that thing in like 1 minute.)).

Oh, and I would definitely read (skim) the documentation for interesting features such as getting the cell types etc of xlrd/xlwt. It's worth it, if only because it's short and will save you the learning curve of experimenting.

Super short example of xlwt:

```
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')

supersecretdata = [34,123,4,1234,12,34,12,41,234,123,4,123,1,45123,5,43,61,3,56]

for i,e in enumerate(supersecretdata):
    sheet1.write(i,1,e)

name = "random.xls"
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Super short example of xlrd:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
book = open_workbook('random.xls')
sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = []

for i in xrange(sheet1.nrows):
    data.append(sheet1.cell(i,1).value)
```

Comment: WOW at IronSpread. Thats is impressive. Really nice to keep a user in the Excel environment, so no nose bleeds looking at coding.
+1000 to you sir for your answers.

Comment: one caveat, i just noticed some slight compatibility issues with Office 64 bit version, throws some errors on exiting Excel, but seems to work. Hopefully a 64bit version is in the pipeline soon.

Comment: Which has compatibility issues?

Comment: It seems that Ironspread does not fully like Excel 64bit.
On excel open, a dialog states "Failed to Load xll"
I disabled every other Addin and also COM addins, but like I said, it works perfectly after I dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Well, give them time. It's a new product.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing both the cell row number in Range and need to increment cell row after each iteration of the loop.

```
sh.Range("A1").Offset(0,x).Value = i
```

This change should work.

```
class XcelExport():
    def excel(self):
        app = 'Excel'
        xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('%s.Application' % app)
        ss = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\MyFile.xls')
        sh = ss.ActiveSheet
        xl.Visible = True
        sleep(.1)  
        sh.Cells(1,1).Value = 'Export-to-%s : Items' % app
        sleep(.1)
        x=0
        for i in EventTableRFT:
            sh.Range("A1").Offset(0,x).Value = i #You need to increment the cell row
            x+=1
        sh.Cells(i+2,1).Value = "End of the List!"

xprt = XcelExport()
xprt.excel()
```

Comment: thanks, did you mean to write `x++` as `x+1`.
the error that occurs when I run:
`  File "C:\MyFile.py", line 195, in excel
    sh.Range("A1").Offset(0,Rowx).Value = i #You need to increment the cell row 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Range.py", line 686, in __call__
    , ColumnIndex)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 459, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),`
<:continued next:>

Comment: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)`

By any chance, does the fact I am running Win and Office 64bit affect the COM connection? (I know i had that problem with another software recently using ActiveX)

Comment: I've updated my post to fix the issue you addressed in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Signal(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'x': self.x,
            'y': self.y,
        }

def file_save_excel(dataset, filename, sheet_name, new_sheet):
    dataset = dataset.applymap(lambda x: x.encode('unicode_escape').
                               decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x)

    print('Writing the processed dataset to excel file...')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    if os.path.exists(filename) and new_sheet:
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        writer.book = book

    dataset.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
    return True

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([s.to_dict() for s in signals])
file_save_excel(dataframe, 'FileName.xlsx', 'SheetName', True)
```