# Matching strings of a List of lists and export them to an Excel

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a list of lists and I want to match items of each list by string "Name" and "Address" and I want to export the matched items to an Excel

```
['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    b.resolvers.level3.net\r', 'Address:  4.2.2.2\r', '\r', ''],
['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    google-public-dns-a.google.com\r', 'Address:  8.8.8.8\r', '\r', ''],
['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    dns.quad9.net\r', 'Address:  9.9.9.9\r', '\r', '']


import re
m = re.search(r'\bName\b'| \bAddress\b', line)
for line in output:
        if m:
            print(m.group())
```

What I want to write :

```
b.resolvers.level3.net , 4.2.2.2
google-public-dns-a.google.com , 8.8.8.8
dns.quad9.net , 9.9.9.9
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the lists, you have two `Address:` you want to match them both?

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to convert your array structure to a `dict` structure by parsing the data and putting it into something like `{'Server': 'Corp', 'Address':'10.17.2.5', ...}` ? That way, getting at the data will be much easier?!

Comment: @RAN_0915 : want to match the second address only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
lists=[['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    b.resolvers.level3.net\r', 'Address:  4.2.2.2\r', '\r', ''],['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    google-public-dns-a.google.com\r', 'Address:  8.8.8.8\r', '\r', ''],
['Server:  Corp', 'Address:  10.17.2.5\r', '\r', 'Name:    dns.quad9.net\r', 'Address:  9.9.9.9\r', '\r', '']]

list2=[]
for singleList in lists:
    list1=[]
    flag=0    

    for item in singleList:
        matcher=re.search('Name:(.*)', item)
        if matcher:
            list1.append(matcher.group(1).strip())
            print(matcher.group(1).strip())
            flag=1

        if flag==1:
            matcher=re.search('Address:(.*)', item)
            if matcher:
                list1.append(matcher.group(1).strip())
                print(matcher.group(1).strip())

    list2.append(list1)

import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')


for j,a in enumerate(list2):
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        sheet1.write(j,i,e)

name = "random.xls"
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

`lists` will be the list of lists. The list2 contains

`[['b.resolvers.level3.net', '4.2.2.2'], ['google-public-dns-a.google.com', '8.8.8.8'], ['dns.quad9.net', '9.9.9.9']]` which can be exported to an excel or a csv

Comment: can it be in the exact order what i have mentioned in my question. Actually i will be exporting that to excel so that "Name" will be there against "IP" ?

Comment: what order?  You want the name and ip in a list or just as a string to print

Comment: yeah.. name,ip..can it be exported to excel ? ip against name ?

Comment: Yes you can. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766833/export-a-python-list-to-excel

Comment: I checked that but don’t know how to integrate that with your script .. it doesn’t give “ip”in one column and “name”in another column in excel....

Comment: getting error " list1=[] IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: i got the "name" and 'address" for last list of nested list..value of first 2 list are missing ... i think it got overwrite instead of appending

Comment: you just copy the whole code in the answer and execute