# Saving Dataframe statistics into an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I recently picked up Python two weeks ago, and have learned so much these past two weeks. I am filtering data with Pandas library, and it's been great! However, I am stuck trying to save my statistical data.

Here is my code:

```
x53=df8['Header1'].max()
y53=df8['Header1'].min()
z53=df8['Header1'].mean()
k53=df8['Header1'].mode()

x55=df7['Header2'].max()
y55=df7['Header2'].min()
z55=df7['Header2'].mean()
k55=df7['Header2'].mode()
```

I am looking for max,min,avg and mode in different columns which have been filtered.

How can I write this data into an excel file? I have alot more statics, which are in different data frames. But I want to be able to populate a matrix in excel using the statistics i'm calculating in pandas.

This is what i've tried so far:
(1)

```
Data = [x53,y53,z53,k53]
df1.to_excel("another_100.xlsx", sheet_name="Filtered Data", index= False)
```

(2)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x0', 'y0','z0','k0'], ['x7', 'y7','z7','k7']],
                
               index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
               columns=['col 1', 'col 2','col 3','col 4'])

df.to_excel("outputzz.xlsx")
```

(3)

```
wb1 = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb1.add_sheet('sheet1')

ws.write(4, 0, x1)
ws.write(1, 0, y1)
ws.write(2, 0, z1)
ws.write(2, 1, k1)
ws.write(2, 2, 1)


wb1.save('yu.xlsx')
```

Thank You,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store scalar values in excel cells, this works:

```
df = {"col1":[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'col2':[2,4,1,3,5,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.to_excel("another_100.xlsx", sheet_name="Filtered Data", index= False)
```

Also, you may add matrices in cells as follows ( if this is how you want to add them )

```
matrix1 = [[1,1],[1,1]]
matrix2 = [[2,2],[2,2]]

df = {"my_matrices":[matrix1,matrix2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.to_excel("stats.xlsx", sheet_name="Filtered Data", index= False)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the second method you have done, but I do have an additional question for you.

Comment: your welcome, looking forward to you other question.

Answer (score 0):

*pandas* is a very powerfull module indeed. It is intended to process tabular data. However, if you just want to save a *list* to CSV, there is no need to convert if first to a *pandas.DataFrame* object. Have a look at [this](https://pythonguides.com/python-write-a-list-to-csv/) short guide on writing python to CSV.

You could go with

```
# import module
import csv 

Data = [x53,y53,z53,k53]
df1.to_excel(, sheet_name="Filtered Data", index= False)

# open csv file for writing:
with open("another_100.csv", 'w') as f:
    # create writer object
    write = csv.writer(f) 
    # write
    write.writerows(Data ) 
# the file is automatically closed when the identation is closed/finished
```

If you like to write to an Excel sheet, there is are different specific modules for this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766833/export-a-python-list-to-excel#11778645) post. It suggests to use [XLWT](http://www.python-excel.org), of which you find an example below tailored to your needs.

```py
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

# create workbook object
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Filtered Data")


for i,e in enumerate(Data):
    sheet1.write(i,1,e)

name = "another_100.xls" # does not support xlsx files
book.save(name)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

Comment: Hello, I was using pandas to slice data from an excel file. I had to filter the data based on the values of entries on a set of columns. Is there a better way to do this?